# Find comma into dataframe and return the row (in r)

Tags: r

I want to find a comma in a dataframe and return the rows where it was found.
the data is like this
 [r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osTDT.png)

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post your data as text rather as an image, and a minimal working code that you've tried, so that we can copy-paste-run it and build from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pasting all columns together you can find the rows that contains a comma:

An example with a dummy dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(Var=c("a,a","a","a","a,a","a"), Var2 = c("b","b,b","b","b","b"))
df2<-apply(df,1,paste,collapse="")
which(grepl(",",df2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column flagging the rows where a comma was found and then filter the data frame for the flagged rows.

```
data <- data %>%
     mutate(flag = ifelse(str_detect(columnC, ",")|str_detect(columnD, ",")|str_detect(columnE, ","), 1, 0) %>%
     filter(flag==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(grepl(',', .)))
```

**Output:**

```
     X1 X2    X3
1 1,2,3  a 2,3,4
2   2,3  b     a
3     4  c     4
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c("1,2,3", "2,3", "4"),
                 X2 = letters[1:3],
                 X3 = c("2,3,4", "a", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that your data frame is stored in a variable `df`.
You can find the rows that have a comma using the `stringr` package and the `apply` function :

```
df=cbind(1:4,c("oko","kokk","rk,ki","plok"),c("er,t","plo","oli","rte"))
library(stringr)
inds_row=which(apply(df,1,function(x){ifelse(sum(str_detect(x,','))>0,T,F)})==T)
inds_row
> [1] 1 3
```

Kind regards,

Smich

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `base R`

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, grepl, pattern = ",")),]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1,2,3", "2,3", 
"4"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", 
 "b", "c"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("2,3,4", 
 "4", "a"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -3L))
```